# Ajax request only submits last one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code in a file called 'inject.php' which i use to retrieve an update multiple values in-game but the request is only getting the last value "health" and displaying the health in all the other feilds :/

```js
 < script type = "text/javascript" >
   function getAttack() {
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       // Create the object for browsers
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {
       // Create the object for browser versions prior to IE 7
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         // if server is ready with the response
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
           // if everything is Ok on browser
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             //Update the div with the response
             document.getElementById("attack").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
         }
       }
       //send the selected option id to the php page 
     xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/fetchAttack.php", true);
     xmlhttp.send();
   }

 function getDefense() {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // Create the object for browsers
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
     // Create the object for browser versions prior to IE 7
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       // if server is ready with the response
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         // if everything is Ok on browser
         if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           //Update the div with the response
           document.getElementById("defense").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
       }
     }
     //send the selected option id to the php page 
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/fetchDefense.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }

 function getMoney() {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // Create the object for browsers
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
     // Create the object for browser versions prior to IE 7
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       // if server is ready with the response
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         // if everything is Ok on browser
         if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           //Update the div with the response
           document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
       }
     }
     //send the selected option id to the php page 
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/fetchMoney.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }

 function getRank() {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // Create the object for browsers
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
     // Create the object for browser versions prior to IE 7
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       // if server is ready with the response
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         // if everything is Ok on browser
         if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           //Update the div with the response
           document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
       }
     }
     //send the selected option id to the php page 
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/fetchRank.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }

 function getExp() {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // Create the object for browsers
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
     // Create the object for browser versions prior to IE 7
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       // if server is ready with the response
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         // if everything is Ok on browser
         if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           //Update the div with the response
           document.getElementById("exp").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
       }
     }
     //send the selected option id to the php page 
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/fetchExp.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }

 function getLevel() {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // Create the object for browsers
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
     // Create the object for browser versions prior to IE 7
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       // if server is ready with the response
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         // if everything is Ok on browser
         if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           //Update the div with the response
           document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
       }
     }
     //send the selected option id to the php page 
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/fetchLevel.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }

 function getHealth() {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // Create the object for browsers
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
     // Create the object for browser versions prior to IE 7
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       // if server is ready with the response
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         // if everything is Ok on browser
         if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           //Update the div with the response
           document.getElementById("health").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
       }
     }
     //send the selected option id to the php page 
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/fetchHealth.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
 setInterval(getAttack, 1000);
 setInterval(getDefense, 1000);
 setInterval(getMoney, 1000);
 setInterval(getRank, 1000);
 setInterval(getExp, 1000);
 setInterval(getLevel, 1000);
 setInterval(getHealth, 1000);

 < /script>
```

Comment: Using global variables to hold the xmlHttpRequest object. Bad idea.

Comment: add var xmlhttp; in first line of every function and check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add

```
var xmlhttp;
```

to the top of each function

Currently you're using a global `xmlhttp` variable, so each function clobbers the value of the xmlhttp

Answer (score 0):

As you are not using `var xmlhttp;` it is becoming a global variable and getting overwritten by each function. So the last function is setting the URL of the AJAX call to `"ajax/fetchHealth.php"`. So basically all the function is sending the request to the same URL and getting back the same response. Hope this helps.